# Linkedin Integration

Tags: java, android, performance, android-studio, linkedin-api

Hello i have a integration linkedin sdk

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my_package"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.01"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        sdkTest {
            storeFile file("/home/xx/Escritorio/android-studio/bin/app.jks")
            storePassword "1234567"
            keyAlias "Package Hash"
            keyPassword "1234567"
        }

        release {
             storeFile file("/home/xx/Escritorio/android-studio/bin/app.jks")
            storePassword "1234567"
            keyAlias "Package Hash"
            keyPassword "1234567"
        }
    }
}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile project(':linkedin-sdk')
}
```

and reviced this error

```
 E/LINKEDING ERROR 1﹕ {
    "errorCode": "INVALID_REQUEST",
    "errorMessage": "either bundle id or package name \/ hash are invalid, unknown, malformed"
    }
```

whats is a way to integrate fine a linkedin
how to fix this code?

I'm not sure you can go inside file build.gradle

this working but when user acept linkedin auth im recived this error

Comment: Have you gone through the steps documented by LinkedIn to register your application's package & hash values?   https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk#application

Comment: on my storeFile file is a file for created apk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error occurs may be because the hash key you used to integrate your app with LinkedIn is wrong.

I faced the same problem a while ago and found out that hash key generated through terminal was wrong. You can use the following method to generate hash key through your java code :

```
public void generateHashkey(){
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                PACKAGE,
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());

            Log.e("Hash key", ""+Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(),Base64.NO_WRAP));
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

You can check the following tutorial for complete process of [Android Integration of LinkedIn and Login](https://www.numetriclabz.com/android-linkedin-integration-login-tutorial) in android app