# Generating a debug key hash value for linkedin login for android Application

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I want linkedin login to be integrated in my Android app.

for that i need to  Generate a debug key hash value for linkedin

when i checked the documentation they said to install openssl and and run the command

```
keytool -exportcert -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

i tried executing this in "C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin" in "cmd" i got a respose of :-

```
'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

when i executed this in C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_66\bin "cmd"i got a response:-

```
*username\.android\debug.keystore
keytool -exportcert [OPTION]...

Exports certificate

Options:

 -rfc                            output in RFC style
 -alias <alias>                  alias name of the entry to process
 -file <filename>                output file name
 -keystore <keystore>            keystore name
 -storepass <arg>                keystore password
 -storetype <storetype>          keystore type
 -providername <providername>    provider name
 -providerclass <providerclass>  provider class name
 -providerarg <arg>              provider argument
 -providerpath <pathlist>        provider classpath
 -v                              verbose output
 -protected                      password through protected mechanism

Use "keytool -help" for all available commands
2jmj7l5rSw0yVb/vlWAYkK/YBwk=*
```

please guide me if is there any problem with the command or the loctaion where i m executing the command or any thing else ...

Answer (score 5):

In order to generate key hash for Linked follow these steps suggested by @Mr Vijay Arora.

1. Download `Openssl` from: [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads).
2. Make a openssl folder in C drive.
3. Extract Zip files into this openssl folder created in C Drive.
4. Copy the File `debug.keystore` from **.android** folder find like (C:\Users\USER_NAME.android) and paste into jre\bin Folder.
5. Open command prompt and give the path of jre\bin folder like (C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin).
6. Copy the following code and hit enter

   keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore > c:\openssl\bin\debug.txt
7. Now enter password, default password = android.
8. If you see in openssl bin folder, you will get a file with the name of **debug.txt**
9. Now either you can restart command prompt or work with existing command prompt
10. Get back to C drive and give the path of openssl's bin folder
11. copy the following code and paste

    openssl sha1 -binary debug.txt > debug_sha.txt
12. you will get debug_sha.txt in openssl bin folder
13. Again copy following code and paste

    openssl base64 -in debug_sha.txt > debug_base64.txt
14. you will get debug_base64.txt in openssl bin folder
15. open debug_base64.txt file Here is your Key hash.

**OR [Alternative process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34236976/6451573) :**

```
public void generateHashkey(){
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                PACKAGE,
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());

            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.package_name)).setText(info.packageName);
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.hash_key)).setText(Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(),
                                                              Base64.NO_WRAP));
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried using: keytool -exportcert -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64 (mac) , but this gave me a code that did not work. Using the generateHashKey function gave me a working debug code. Thank you very much!